# Проблема с Чат-ботом Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Проблема следующего характера: мне нужно, чтобы бот начал мне отвечать просто зеркально на мои сообщения.

Внизу написал код по уроку. Но бот не реагирует, только принимает сообщения и молчит. В чем может быть проблема? Мой первый опыт, заранее прошу строго не судить.

```
import config
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

#log lvl
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO) 

#bot init
bot = Bot('6106428940:AAESduInoIVDJdrL0YyG9xirICVXPZTRMkM')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

#echo
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)

if __name__ =="_main_":
    executor.start_polling(dp,skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: **АККУРАТНО!** Вы случайно показали токен своего бота! Скорее его сбросьте!

Comment: Это вообще не важно, там пустой бот я смогу создать еще кучу новых. Мне нужно понять сам принцип почему не работает.

Comment: Хорошо, только в следующий раз, когда будете публиковать код, проверяйте его на случаи появления приватных данных (токенов, паролей, и т.д.).

Comment: у вас в коде `if __name__ == "_main_":`, а должно быть `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: возможно моя реакция немного преждевременна. НО СПАСИБО!!!! я 2 дня искал в чем проблема просто пол ютьюба пересмотрел! все заработало!